# How to counteract the scalling of the x and y coordinate when getting closer to the object

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

At the moment I am working on a computer vision project. In this project I am trying to create a 3d marker tracking system with stereo vision. I am able to calibrate both camera's at the same time using a chessboard pattern. After that both camera's are stereo calibrated. when the calibration is complied,  both cameras video's are tracked, points undistorted and rectified. The last step is the triangulation function in OpenCV of both the marker positions. This determent the z coordinate with good enough precision. Only when a object gets closer to the camera lens the distance between the objects changes because of the pin hole principle. only when your working with body segment lengths they should not change this will lead to invalid results.

When comparing the size change of the two markers when getting closer. it seems that the change in size correlates precisely with the z coordinate behavier. With this knowledge there should be a way to correct the x and y position when something gets closer or further away from the lens.

My question is: is there a function in OpenCV witch can adjust the scaling problem of the x and y coordinate accordingly to the z axis changes, otherwise is there a reliable methode of changing the x an y coordinates?

Comment: I can't follow you...  using an entocentric camera lens distance is inversly proportional to image scale. what do you want to do? I don't get your problem

Comment: I am planning to use stereo vision for mocap. Only when you get closer to the camera the length of segment will change because of how a camera works. But the length of the segment does not change in real life. My question is how can I compensate for this so that my segments stay the same length when moving away of getting closer tot the camera?